# Java A->B->C so A ->C?

Tags: java, build

A have jar B in build path,
B have jar C in build path,

Can I use classes in C in A ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Err can you give us more information? If this is Eclipse, then it will probably figure it out for you. If you mean in PRD code then nested JARs dont work, no.

Comment: No, you will have to include C in the classpath of A.

Answer (score 0):

If you have A, B and C in your class path you can use any of these classes from any other class. All you need is a reference or a reference to a reference etc.

Answer (score 0):

having jar b and jar c in build path is not enough.
You can use any of these options to achieve what  you want:

1. add a new line in jar b manifest containing 
   Class-Path: c.jar
   add a new line to jar a manifest containing
   Class-Path: b.jar
2. `java -cp a.jar;b.jar;c.jar  yourfullclassname`

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to distinguish between building these jars and the subsequent usage.

e.g. you can build jar B referencing jar C, but the two would need to be deployed together. If you don't then in your build for jar A, you reference jar B, but it wouldn't work without jar C.

Your build could alternatively take the code for B, and package it together with the contents of jar C. *Then* you could use B and C together in A.

This dependency management can become quite complex (as you can see). Packaging code together such that you don't have to provide multiple jars makes life easy (you only reference one jar), but it makes upgrades a pain (you can't upgrade, say, one common lib). Tools like Maven provide options for dealing with this (do I need this jar for compilation only, do I package it with my program, is it used for testing only etc.)